# Accessing Objective-C hidden _cmd argument from Python

Tags: objective-c, nslog, pyobjc

I've poked around at the PyObjC innards quite a bit trying to figure this out. Is it possible to access Objective-C's hidden `SEL _cmd` method argument when writing a Python method? It's got to be generated at some point, but I'm not sure if that point is one at which my Python code can get to it.

I was mostly interested in this in order to be able to make an easy PyObjC `NSLog` text macro:

```
def meth_(self, arg):
    NSLog(u"%s called" % _cmd)
```

although I have found other ways to do this kind of logging in Python (see Jeremy's answer), so at this point it's become curiosity about the PyObjC bridge.

Answer (score 3):

Why not go about it by logging the name of the Python function, instead? Then you can apply a Python approach to getting the function name, like throwing an exception and munging around in the stack trace, as shown in [this code snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/144838-include-function-name-and-line-number-automaticall/).

***ETA:*** [This code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66062-determining-current-function-name/) demonstrates the "better way" mentioned in the prior snippet as introduced in Python 2.1: using `sys._getframe()`. It is far simpler.

Comment: Indeed. I've seen these and made use of the second when necessary. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Python. But in objective-C instead `_cmd` you can find method selector by:

```
const id* selfPtr = &self;
SEL sel = *(SEL*)(void*)(--selfPtr);
```

May be you can use same approach in Python.